# Grid with points

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, grid-layout

I want to create  grid with little circles  4 x 4

something like that :

[image]

I created the circle that will be used for the grid , but can't figure out how to create the grid with initializing the 4x4 grid with this circle

```
class PracticeView: UIView {
let box = UIView()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    circles()
}

func circles() {
    let diameter = 10
    let centerCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x:  Int(box.frame.size.width)  + 20 , y: Int(box.frame.size.height) + 20 , width: diameter, height: diameter))
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    centerCirclePath.fill()
   }
}
```

I think that I must make for-in loop in another for-in loop to create the grid and then somehow to initialize the circle somehow ,but I am not too sure because I`m new in swift.

Comment: Can you post your first attempt?

Comment: @Siriss  well I make only the for-in loop in another for-in loop as some example , because I dont know how to implement the circle so the grid can be done
`let  x = 4 
let  y = 4

for build1 in 0..<x {
 for build2 in 0..<y {
 }
}`
  I think the for-in loop must be something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    drawCirclesGrid()
}

func drawCirclesGrid() {
    let diameter: CGFloat = 10
    let points: CGFloat = 4 // number of points that are needed ( hard coded ! )

    let cellWidth = bounds.width / points

    let cellHeight = bounds.height  / points

    for i in 0..<Int(points) {

        for j in 0..<Int(points) {

            let circleX: CGFloat = ((CGFloat(i) + 0.5) * cellWidth)

            let circleY: CGFloat =  ((CGFloat(j) + 0.5) * cellHeight)

            let centerCirclePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: circleX, y: circleY, width: diameter, height: diameter))

            let  customlayer = CAShapeLayer()
            customlayer.path = centerCirclePath.cgPath
            customlayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(customlayer)
        }
    }
```